# jUnit: How to test mandatory attributes of Entity

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm quite new to `jUnit` testing and I'm trying to write some `integration test` for my `Spring Boot` application. My plan is to test, whether all mandatory attributes of an object are set. I came up with something like:

```
@Test(expected = org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException.class)
public void testMessageMandatoryAttributes() {
    Message corruptedMessage = new Message();
    // set id
    // corruptedMessage.setId(id);
    // set conversation thread
    // corruptedMessage.setConversationThread(conversationThread);
    messageRepository.save(corruptedMessage);
}
```

Nevertheless my Message entity has more mandatory attributes...how to test in just one function that all of them are properly set?

Comment: I do not get it. It seems that you are setting all attributes on your own (via setters in the test) so what do you want to test?

Comment: Would you mind posting your java code for which you want to write the test for? It will be easier to see what JUnit tests you require then

Comment: @pgiecek My goal is to create a test that says "You tried to create an object and save it to the database, nevertheless you didn't assign all mandatory attributes, so you got this exception for this and this and this field and that's, how it should be...."

Comment: OK. Basically you want to test that method `messageRepository.save(Message)` throws an exception containing some information about missing fields, right?

Comment: @deeveeABC there is nothing much to post...I have an Entity, which I want to save to a database via Spring JPA and I want to write a fail test that will test that all mandatory fields (defined by the database structure) are filled in....or more like vice - versa - that none of them is filled and it will throw exceptions for all of them (which will be awaited).

Comment: Ahh... now I also understand your question! I was a little bit confused like @pgiecek

Comment: Are you coding the repository yourself or are you using Spring Data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to test that `messageRepository.save(Message)` method throws an exception containing some information about missing fields.

Find below a code snippet that may help you to achieve your goal. Replace the assertion in the catch-block with whatever you need to verify.

```
@Test
public void testMessageMandatoryAttributes() {
    Message corruptedMessage = new Message();
    // set id
    // corruptedMessage.setId(id);
    // set conversation thread
    // corruptedMessage.setConversationThread(conversationThread);

   try {
       messageRepository.save(corruptedMessage);
       fail();
   catch (YourException e) {
       assertEquals("Expected value", e.getXxx());
       // ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert exception then I would suggest using `ExpectedException`. If you want to verify object properties then I would suggest to use write you custom matcher.